# "Cannot use import statement outside a module", even as mjs

Tags: express, import, export

I have been trying to import a simple function that says "Blah Blah" to my express server.
Unfortunately I am getting the error: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.
I have tried to google this issue the whole day, tried to change the file to .mjs and more, but the server keeps crashing with this error regardless of the methods I found online.

**ExpressServer.js :**

```
//start express server
const express = require("express");
const server = express();
const path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
//Require functions that saves to DB
import {saveToDB} from './saveToDB.js';

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// parse application/json
server.use(bodyParser.json());

server.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("express server is running..");
});

//Send form details to DB

server.get("/save", (req, res) => {
  phone = req.body.number;
  name = req.body.name;
  saveToDB();
});
```

**saveToDB.js**

```
const saveToDB = () => {
  console.log(`Blah blah blah`);
};

export default saveToDB;
```

**The error:**

```
import {saveToDB} from ('./saveToDB.js');
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: Which node version are you using? `node -v` I mean

Comment: @leonardfactory v12.14.1

Answer (score 1):

First, check what Node version you are using. If it's 13 or above, ES6 and thus the import statement is supported. Else, you have to update your node version or use the ES5 way (*require*) instead of *import*. 
Second: If the version is 13 or above, you can either change your file extension to *.mjs* or add *{ "type": "module" }* to you *package.json* file. 
Third: Always put your import statements at the top of the file. Also, I would probably not mix *require* with *import*, but that's personal preference.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my version to 14 and now this error does not  occur after setting the type in the package.json file. I have no idea why it happened, as I have imported a lot of stuff in the past.

Anyway, I now get "const express = require("express");
                ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

Problem was fixed, apparently the problem starts when you try to use import on server side instead of require. If you still wish to use import you can update your node version and edit the type in package.json.

If you choose to go with the first route, you will also have to change all the "Require" in your file to import, otherwise you will get "ReferenceError: require is not defined"

The easier solution would be to change:

```
import {saveToDB} from './saveToDB.js';
```

With

```
const saveToDB = require("./saveToDB.js");
```

And in the exported module, use the older exporting method:

```
module.exports = saveToDB;
```